# How to reboot domain(virtual machine) after shutdown it using php-libvirt

Tags: php, virtual-machine, libvirt

**How to reboot domain(virtual machine) after shutdown it using php-libvirt:**

Am new to PHP livbvirt. and i successfully listed the all domains in server. and get resource of particular domain and call the shutdown function.

```
$res = libvirt_domain_lookup_by_name($conn, $name);

$stop = libvirt_domain_shutdown($res);
```

Now shut-downed domain is not display in domain list.

Now the problem is how to reboot/restart that domain again? libvirt having function for reboot, that is,

```
libvirt_domain_create($res);
```

My doubt is what is argument here, how to get that shut-downed domain resources.

Any one kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, you can create the shutdown guest by using the XML config file. From the documentation, you can use like:

```
libvirt_domain_create_xml($conn, $xml)
```